# how to speed up the select statement among multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select-query

Do you have any idea how I can improve the following sql select query? It takes a while to get results even in sql management studio. So, it takes longer when I call it from the website. I get the top 15 results but it still takes time to get results. Is it because of the sub-queries?

```
SELECT top 15  t1.TagId, t1.TagName, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TagsToPost 
                WHERE TagsToPost.TagId=t1.TagId AND 
                EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Posts 
                             WHERE PostId=TagsToPost.PostId AND 
                             Posts.Time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND
                             Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId)) as myCount

FROM Tags as t1

WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TagsToPost 
                WHERE TagsToPost.TagId=t1.TagId AND 
                EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Posts 
                             WHERE PostId=TagsToPost.PostId AND 
                             Posts.Time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND
                             Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId))>1

ORDER BY myCount DESC
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry for missing those details. I included sql-server in tags now. It retrieves the tags along with counts. Users post questions, and when they ask question they choose a tag. I use TimePointId to categorize questions for different time intervals defined. So, I am trying to retreive the popular tags for that time interval (timepointid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you only need to run the subquery once:

```
SELECT top 15 *
FROM (SELECT t1.TagId, t1.TagName, 
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM TagsToPost 
              WHERE TagsToPost.TagId=t1.TagId AND 
                    EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM Posts 
                            WHERE PostId=TagsToPost.PostId AND 
                                  Posts.Time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND
                                  Posts.TimePointId=@TimePointId
                           )
             ) as myCount
      FROM Tags as t1
     ) t
WHERE COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY myCount DESC;
```

I'm not sure that SQL Server will optimize it to eliminate generating one result set so this might cut the query time in half.

Then, you can eliminate one level of `exists` by using a standard `group by` and `join`:

```
      SELECT top 15 t.TagId, t.TagName, COUNT(*) as myCount
      FROM tags t join
           TagsToPost tp
           on TagsToPost.TagId = t.TagId AND 
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM Posts  p
                    WHERE p.PostId = tp.PostId AND 
                          p.Time > '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND
                          p.TimePointId=@TimePointId
                   )
      GROUP BY t.TagId, t.TagName
      HAVING myCOunt > 1
      ORDER BY myCount DESC;
```

You could do something similar with `posts`.  But it is probably sufficient to create an index `Posts(PostId, TimePointId, Time)`.